# Looking for a Billings Pro alternative

Tags: software-recommendation

Like the title says, i'm looking for a program (preferably free!) that has similar features to Billings Pro. I'm a part-time web developer and it was unnecessary to have to pay for Billings Pro just to have a program to create 2-3 invoices per month.

What i'm looking for is a program that will let me:

- Create Invoices
- Create recurring Invoices
- Create Clients

Does anyone know a (free) program can do the above things?

Comment: As written it is hard to see why simply using Pages to create the invoices and Numbers to keep track of open payments isn't going to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find an old copy of Billings (pre Pro), that still works without the subscription, I would grab that. I've been using my copy for the last 5 years with no need to switch to the subscription model. A quick google and I found this: http://billings.en.softonic.com/mac but I don't personally know this site.

Comment: Can you tell me which version do you have? I need to know what i'm looking for :)

Comment: Sorry @user2093301 it's installed on my laptop at home, but I'm 99% sure it's Billings 3 from the screenshots that I checked on Google. While Googling, I also saw you can buy it on Amazon for less than $10.